# java code execution yields to different results in debug without breakpoints and normal run. Is ExecutorService broken?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, executorservice, java-threads

TL:DR  `ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);`
in debug runs concurrent, but in normal runtime it starts concurrent, but later runs in single thread.

I have some code where I start 4 different tasks in `ExecutorService`. Two of those tasks should finish almost instantly, the other two should run for a while.

Those tasks return execution time in seconds in `Future<Double>`.

This code is responsible for task execution and measurement:

```
public Future<Double> measure(int[] arr, ProcessIntArray processIntArray, ExecutorService es) {
    Callable<Double> task = () -> {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        processIntArray.process(arr);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        return (end - start) / 1000000000.0;
    };
    return es.submit(task);
}
```

Later on, after starting those tasks, I print them in the order of execution time from previous runs for the same input size.

```
    Future<Double> bubbleSortTime = measure(bubbleSortArray, Solution::bubbleSort, executorService);
    Future<Double> insertionSortTime = measure(insertionSortArray, Solution::insertionSort, executorService);
    Future<Double> quickSortTime = measure(quickSortArray, Solution::quickSort, executorService);
    Future<Double> mergeSortTime = measure(mergeSortArray, Solution::mergeSort, executorService);


    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("array size:     " + size);
    System.out.println("quick sort:     " + quickSortTime.get() + "s");
    System.out.println("merge sort:     " + mergeSortTime.get() + "s");
    System.out.println("insertion sort: " + insertionSortTime.get() + "s");
    System.out.println("bubble sort:    " + bubbleSortTime.get() + "s");
```

When I run code in debug mode, 2 results are printed immidiately, and I have to wait a while for 3rd result (I do not bother waiting for the 4th one).

After starting in debug (correct and expected):

`array size:     1000000
quick sort:     0.186892839s
merge sort:     0.291950604s
insertion sort: 344.534256723s`

Normal execution differs, It looks like in method measure   `long start = System.nanoTime();` is executed, then thread falls asleep, and after insertionSort is done, quickSort is back in execution, which yields to output:

`array size:     1000000
quick sort:     345.893922141s
merge sort:     345.944023095s
insertion sort: 345.871908569s`

Which is wrong. All of those threads should be running at the same time, as from newFixedThreadPool javadoc.

```
/**
 * Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads
 * operating off a shared unbounded queue.  At any point, at most
 * {@code nThreads} threads will be active processing tasks.
 * If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active,
 * they will wait in the queue until a thread is available.
 * If any thread terminates due to a failure during execution
 * prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to
 * execute subsequent tasks.  The threads in the pool will exist
 * until it is explicitly {@link ExecutorService#shutdown shutdown}.
 *
 * @param nThreads the number of threads in the pool
 * @return the newly created thread pool
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code nThreads <= 0}
 */
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)
```

I attach source code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class ThreadedSortingComparsion {
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    void popul(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = random.nextInt();
        }
    }

    interface ArraySorter {
        void sort(int[] array);
    }

    public Future<Double> measureTime(int[] array, ArraySorter arraySorter, ExecutorService executorService) {
        Callable<Double> task = () -> {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            arraySorter.sort(array);
            long end = System.nanoTime();
            return (end - start) / 1000000000.0;
        };
        return executorService.submit(task);
    }


    public void start() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

        int size = 1000 * 1000;
        int[] quickSortArray = new int[size];
        popul(quickSortArray);
        int[] bubbleSortArray = Arrays.copyOf(quickSortArray, quickSortArray.length);
        int[] mergeSortArray = Arrays.copyOf(quickSortArray, quickSortArray.length);
        int[] originalArray = Arrays.copyOf(quickSortArray, quickSortArray.length);
        int[] insertionSortArray = Arrays.copyOf(quickSortArray, quickSortArray.length);

        Future<Double> bubbleSortTime = measureTime(bubbleSortArray, ThreadedSortingComparsion::bubbleSort, executorService);
        Future<Double> insertionSortTime = measureTime(insertionSortArray, ThreadedSortingComparsion::insertionSort, executorService);
        Future<Double> quickSortTime = measureTime(quickSortArray, ThreadedSortingComparsion::quickSort, executorService);
        Future<Double> mergeSortTime = measureTime(mergeSortArray, ThreadedSortingComparsion::mergeSort, executorService);


        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("array size:     " + size);
        System.out.println("quick sort:     " + quickSortTime.get() + "s");
        System.out.println("merge sort:     " + mergeSortTime.get() + "s");
        System.out.println("insertion sort: " + insertionSortTime.get() + "s");
        System.out.println("bubble sort:    " + bubbleSortTime.get() + "s");
        executorService.shutdown();

        for (int i = 0; i < quickSortArray.length; i++) {
            if (quickSortArray[i] != bubbleSortArray[i] || quickSortArray[i] != mergeSortArray[i] || quickSortArray[i] != insertionSortArray[i]) {
                throw new RuntimeException(Arrays.toString(originalArray));
            }
        }
    }


    public static void mergeSort(int[] ar) {
        if (ar.length < 5) {
            bubbleSort(ar);
            return;
        }
        int middle = ar.length / 2;
        int[] arrayLeft = new int[middle];
        int[] arrayRight = new int[ar.length - middle];
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            if (i < middle) {
                arrayLeft[i] = ar[i];
            } else {
                arrayRight[i - middle] = ar[i];
            }
        }
        mergeSort(arrayLeft);
        mergeSort(arrayRight);
        int indexLeft = 0;
        int indexRight = 0;
        int inputArrayIndex = 0;
        while (true) {
            int whatToPutInAR = 0;
            if (indexLeft != arrayLeft.length && indexRight != arrayRight.length) {
                if (arrayLeft[indexLeft] < arrayRight[indexRight]) {
                    whatToPutInAR = arrayLeft[indexLeft];
                    indexLeft++;
                } else {
                    whatToPutInAR = arrayRight[indexRight];
                    indexRight++;
                }
            } else if (indexLeft != arrayLeft.length) {
                whatToPutInAR = arrayLeft[indexLeft];
                indexLeft++;
            } else if (indexRight != arrayRight.length) {
                whatToPutInAR = arrayRight[indexRight];
                indexRight++;
            }
            if (inputArrayIndex == ar.length) return;
            ar[inputArrayIndex++] = whatToPutInAR;
        }
    }

    private static void quickSort(int[] ar) {
        quickSort(ar, 0, ar.length);
    }

    static public void quickSort(int[] array, int start, int end) {
        boolean changed = false;
        if (end == 0) return;
        int pivot = array[end - 1];
        int partitionCandidate = start;
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (array[i] < pivot) {
                swap(array, partitionCandidate++, i);
                changed = true;
            } else if (pivot < array[i]) {
                swap(array, end - 1, i);
                changed = true;
            }
        }
        if (start < partitionCandidate) {
            quickSort(array, start, partitionCandidate);
        }
        if (partitionCandidate < end) {
            if (partitionCandidate != start || changed) quickSort(array, partitionCandidate, end);
        }
    }


    public static void swap(int[] ar, int from, int to) {
        int old = ar[from];
        ar[from] = ar[to];
        ar[to] = old;
    }

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
                if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                    swap(array, j + 1, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void insertionSort(int[] ar) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
                boolean breaker = true;
                if (ar[j] < ar[j - 1]) {
                    breaker = false;
                    swap(ar, j - 1, j);
                }
                if (breaker) break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        ThreadedSortingComparsion s = new ThreadedSortingComparsion();
        s.start();
    }
}
```

Edit: 
when I run it in Ideone, the code works fine.
http://ideone.com/1E8C51
Ideone has java version `1.8.0_51`
I tested in on `1.8.0_91`, `1.8.0_92`. And `1.8.0_45`.
Why does it work on ideone, but not on 2 other PC's I tested?

When I do thread dump, while executing not in the debug, then I wait a while, and after thread dump is printed, also results are printed. So the thread dump is done after finishing insertion sort.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java" -Xmx8G -Xss1G -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Tomasz_Mielczarski\IdeaProjects\untitled\out\production\untitled;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain ThreadedSortingComparsion

array size:     1000000
2016-07-15 13:45:22
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode):

"pool-1-thread-4" #15 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000696bd000 nid=0x560 runnable [0x00000002fffee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.mergeSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:77)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.mergeSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:78)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.mergeSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:78)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.mergeSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:78)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.mergeSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:77)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion$$Lambda$5/81628611.sort(Unknown Source)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.lambda$measureTime$0(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:21)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion$$Lambda$2/1023892928.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-3" #14 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000696bb800 nid=0x2634 runnable [0x00000002bffee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:126)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:126)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:126)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:126)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:126)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:126)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:126)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:126)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:126)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:123)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:126)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:126)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:126)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.quickSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:105)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion$$Lambda$4/1989780873.sort(Unknown Source)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.lambda$measureTime$0(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:21)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion$$Lambda$2/1023892928.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-2" #13 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000696b7800 nid=0x1c70 waiting on condition [0x000000027ffef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000719d72480> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-1" #12 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000696b6800 nid=0x478 runnable [0x000000023ffee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.bubbleSort(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:139)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion$$Lambda$1/990368553.sort(Unknown Source)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.lambda$measureTime$0(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:21)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion$$Lambda$2/1023892928.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Monitor Ctrl-Break" #11 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000068d3d000 nid=0x2f3c runnable [0x00000001fffee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    - locked <0x00000007156892b8> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    - locked <0x00000007156892b8> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain$1.run(AppMain.java:93)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Service Thread" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000068c81000 nid=0x2d6c runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread3" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000068bea800 nid=0x1ad0 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000068be4000 nid=0x17d0 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000068bdd800 nid=0x3238 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000068bda000 nid=0x1824 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000068bd8800 nid=0x910 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000068bd7800 nid=0x31f8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x0000000043229800 nid=0x2810 in Object.wait() [0x00000000fffee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000719d707e0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x0000000719d707e0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000043223000 nid=0xd48 in Object.wait() [0x00000000bffef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000719d78370> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
    - locked <0x0000000719d78370> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000311d800 nid=0x2ed0 waiting on condition [0x000000004311e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000719d58fe0> (a java.util.concurrent.FutureTask)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.start(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:48)
    at ThreadedSortingComparsion.main(ThreadedSortingComparsion.java:162)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000056348800 nid=0x2984 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000043147000 nid=0x27e0 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000043148800 nid=0x20b4 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000004314a000 nid=0x1da4 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000004314c000 nid=0x29e0 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000004314e000 nid=0xa04 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000043150000 nid=0x14b8 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000043153800 nid=0xf00 runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000043154800 nid=0x243c runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000068c82000 nid=0x22d8 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 224

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 13755K [0x0000000715580000, 0x000000071aa80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65536K, 4% used [0x0000000715580000,0x0000000715874910,0x0000000719580000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x0000000719580000,0x0000000719ffa348,0x000000071a000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000071a000000,0x000000071a000000,0x000000071aa80000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 33211K [0x00000005c0000000, 0x00000005cab00000, 0x0000000715580000)
  object space 175104K, 18% used [0x00000005c0000000,0x00000005c206ed30,0x00000005cab00000)
 Metaspace       used 4277K, capacity 4790K, committed 4992K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 484K, capacity 535K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K

quick sort:     355.579434803s
merge sort:     355.629940032s
insertion sort: 355.532578023s
```

Comment: There is no reason for merge and quick sort threads to fall asleep. Even if you only had two cores (or define a pool of 2 threads) you must wait for bubble and insert to finish before merge and quick starts, but their times should be the expected. Maybe there is a peak of CPU or Memory usage when run your program. Have you tried with smaller arrays? Or without the endless loop in the main?

Comment: Hello, on smaller arrays this program acts like multithreaded. But with input of 1m it starts acting like this. Without while(true) in main results are the same. It uses 12,5% - 14% of my cpu (100% of one core) while it has fixed thread pool of 4 and 3 other tasks are waiting for complition.

Comment: It seems that the overloaded CPU produces unexpected behavior. Perhaps the reason why this does not occur in debug mode is because in debug mode read operations and idle processes are interleaved with the arithmetic operations and this affects to the S.O thread scheduler.It is an interesting topic of study.

Comment: Can you post a thread dump taken at the moment when you presume the app runs single-threaded?

Comment: So all threads are there, question only is why you get a different output.

The command line on the thread dump suggest that you are not running ThreadedSortingComparsion directly, but via "com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain".

Run your program directly, on a command line. "java -cp <your_classpath> ThreadedSortingComparsion". See if weird behaviour reproduces. If you need a thread dump, use "jstack <pid>". "jps -l" will list pids of running processes.

Comment: I've got the same output, no matter if I run it from ide or compile and run from command line

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> **TL;DR** HotSpot JIT optimization to eliminate safepoint checks in counted loops played a sick joke.

This is a very interesting question: a simple Java test reveals a non-trivial problem deep inside JVM.

The fact that a thread dump hasn't appeared immediately indicates that the problem is not in Java code, but is somehow related to JVM. Thread dumps are printed at safepoints. The delay means that VM wasn't able to reach a safepoint in short time.

### Background

Certain VM operations (GC, Deoptimization, Thread dump and [some other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666057/analysis-on-gc-logs/29673564#29673564)) are executed at stop-the-world pauses when no Java threads are running. But Java threads could not be stopped at any arbitrary point, they can pause only at certain places called *safepoints*. In JIT-compiled code the safepoints are usually placed at method exits and at backward branches, i.e. inside loops.

The safepoint checks are relatively cheap in terms of perfomance, but not free. That's why JIT compiler tries to reduce number of safepoints where possible.  One such optimization is to eliminate safepoint checks in counted loops, i.e. loops with an integer counter that are known to have finite number of iterations.

### Verify the theory

Let's get back to our test and check if safepoints are reached in time.

Add `-XX:+SafepointTimeout -XX:SafepointTimeoutDelay=1000` JVM options. This should print a debug message whenever VM fails to reach a safepoint in 1000 ms.

```
# SafepointSynchronize::begin: Timeout detected:
# SafepointSynchronize::begin: Timed out while spinning to reach a safepoint.
# SafepointSynchronize::begin: Threads which did not reach the safepoint:
# "pool-1-thread-2" #12 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000019004800 nid=0x1480 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

# SafepointSynchronize::begin: (End of list)
```

Yes, it printed that the thread `pool-1-thread-2` could not stop in 1000 ms. This is the second thread of the Executor's pool, which should run `insertionSort` algorithm.

`insertionSort` has two very long nested counted loops, and it looks like JVM has eliminated safepoint checks inside them. So, if this method runs in compiled mode, JVM cannot stop it until the method completes. If a stop-the-world pause is requested while the method is running, all other threads will also wait.

### What to do?

This issue has been known for a long time. Here is the related JVM bug: [JDK-5014723](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-5014723). It's not a high-priority one, since the problem rarely appears in real-life applications.

A new JVM flag appeared in JDK 8u92 to work around the issue.
`-XX:+UseCountedLoopSafepoints` will always put safepoint checks inside loops.

Another solution would be to transform a long counted loop into generic one by modifying a counter variable inside the loop.

E.g. if you replace `if (breaker) break;` with `if (breaker) j = 0;` the problem will also disappear.

### Why does it work in debug mode then?

When JVM is started with the debugger on, some JIT optimizations are disabled to make the debug info available. In this case the compiled code has all the safepoint checks.

Comment: This answer nicely explains the delay with thread dump. What about the output the OP observes? Does this JIT optimization in the insertion sort somehow prevent merge/quicksort threads from making progress? Or does it have side effects on System.nanoTime()?

Comment: @PavelGrushetzky As soon as safepoint is requested while `insertionSort` is running, all other threads including `quickSort` and `mergeSort` hang waiting for `insertionSort` to complete.

Comment: @apangin thanks, I think i see the overall sequence now: all threads start -> after a while JIT/OSR kicks in and removes safepoints from insertion sort -> safepoint occurs due to GC/deopt/etc -> all threads reach safepoint quickly but insertion sort thread needs to complete both loops -> JVM reaches global safepoint after insertion sort has finished -> then rest of the threads can make progress.

Comment: @PavelGrushetzky Exactly.

Comment: I've came to this question after you absolutely mind-blowing presentation on jug.ru. It seems I can't upvote twice, though. Andrei, please keep on making your presentations and answers on stackoverflow... Because your video appeared you generated a "safepoint" in our office - no one was working for the entire day, all we did is watch your video and try to reproduce things. AMAZING work!