# how to avoid GC pauses?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Our application is latency critical. In order to reduce GC pauses, we reuse objects. In beginning of the process we allocate a lot of small objects and then (almost) no memory allocated. However, I still see following log of gc:

```
2016-12-18T13:51:48.650+0200: 1.085: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0001411 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000203 seconds
2016-12-18T13:51:48.776+0200: 1.210: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002027 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000183 seconds
2016-12-18T13:51:48.894+0200: 1.328: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002559 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000194 seconds
2016-12-18T13:51:48.906+0200: 1.341: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002159 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000199 seconds
2016-12-18T13:51:49.047+0200: 1.482: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002842 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000208 seconds
```

As far, as I understood, JVM stops process to run over all references and mark objects. Is it correct?

Also I see that frequency of such logs decrease with a time. So i think GC tunes some internal parameters and I wish to provide them on the start. Now I run process with following arguments:

```
-Xms10240m
-Xmx10240m
-server
-XX:+UseG1GC
-noclassgc
```

All rest arguments related to verbosing GC. Our machine have enough memory to completely avoid gc. How can I explain it to java?

OS: Linux, JVM either oracle or openJDK.

Thank you.

Comment: 0.0002842 seconds is too long??

Comment: 280 mills, its too long for us.

Comment: 0.0002842 seconds is **not** 280 milliseconds. It's 280 **microseconds**, aka 0.28 milliseconds.

Comment: Oh! you are right, sorry. 280 micro is much better, but we prefer to disable it at completely.

Comment: The G1GC collector are continuously running those micro-collections to **prevent** a long GC run. If you disable those, it'll eventually run out of memory and have to run a full GC, which will be **long** with a 10 Gb heap *(relatively speaking, e.g. many seconds maybe even minutes)*. You'll definitely be feeling *that* when it happens, and it will, eventually and unpredictably. Those micro-collection are exactly what you want in a latency critical system, because a 10+ seconds GC run would kill you.

Comment: Not necessarily. It might very well be the case that you want to avoid these continuous micro collections and do a bigger collection at a time of your choosing. If you have a trading system that runs from 7am to 6pm and can do that without triggering a GC then you might want this optimization and clean up after market hours. Just to give an example

Comment: Its exactly trading system.

Comment: if you're concerned about microseconds you'll have a lot more work cut out of your than just flipping some JVM flags. You might want to look into jhiccup, azul's zing VM, CPU-pinning, wait-free data structures etc. etc. otoh if you're working in HFT i would expect you would already know this...

Comment: @the8472 Azul is too expensive, dedicated cpu per thread - implemented, locking free techniques introduced where the current architecture allows. My main concern now is STW. I though if I will not consume the memory, stw will not happen, but it is. So i asked the help from the community. 
BTW, there is shenandoah gc, which is "almost concurrent" and free alternative to Azul's C4. May be we will migrate on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not necessarily garbage collections.

There is a number of other cases (not related to GC) when JVM prints `Total time for which application threads were stopped`. See [the related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666057/analysis-on-gc-logs/29673564#29673564) for details.

Non-GC safepoints are especially frequent at application start-up time due to class loading and recompilation.

If you want to track GC pauses, use `-XX:+PrintGCDetails`.

**Update**

A few tricks to decrease number of non-GC safepoints:

- `-XX:-UseBiasedLocking` completely disables bias revocation pauses;
- `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:GuaranteedSafepointInterval=0` disables an obligatory safepoint every second;
- `-XX:-TieredCompilation` disables multi-tier compilation thus reducing number of recompilation-related safepoints.

Note: this is just a hint, not a suggestion for production use. The above options may have performance side effects.