# PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, jvm

I have JVM option -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime which prints real "GC stop the world time".

Example:

- Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0018219
  seconds
- Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0016542
  seconds
- Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0015797
  seconds

I need to calculate "GC stop the world" by java code. How can I do it ?

Comment: parse the log file?

Comment: No. I need get this value programmatically.

Comment: @AndrewS No. I need get this value programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that `PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime` prints **safepoint time** rather than **GC time**.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666057/analysis-on-gc-logs/29673564#29673564) for details.

You can get cumulative time of safepoints through JDK-specific (i.e. unsupported) MXBean. This value is equal to the sum of all numbers printed in `Total time for which application threads were stopped` messages.

```
sun.management.HotspotRuntimeMBean runtime =
        sun.management.ManagementFactoryHelper.getHotspotRuntimeMBean();

System.out.println("Safepoint time:  " + runtime.getTotalSafepointTime() + " ms");
System.out.println("Safepoint count: " + runtime.getSafepointCount());
```

Comment: This code do the same as:

for (GarbageCollectorMXBean gc : ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()) {
log.info("Time: bean={} time={}  count={}", gc.getName(), gc.getCollectionCount(), gc.getCollectionCount());
}

I need exactly value from "Total time for which application threads were stopped: VALUE seconds" and "Stopping threads took: VALUE second.

Comment: @ArtemZatsev No, `GarbageCollectorMXBean` values are different. 1) Concurrent GC time is not included in "application threads were stopped". 2) Safepoint pauses occur not only during GC, but also for [many other reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666057/analysis-on-gc-logs/29673564#29673564).

Comment: It's not clear which value you want. The last one? Or all values?

Comment: @AndreiPangin I need value exactly as in "Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0018219 seconds". I need this "0.0018219" value. Maybe you have some ideas how to get it ?

Comment: @ArtemZatsev Mmm. Seems like your intentions are not quite clear even to yourself. Look at the original question - there are three "application threads were stopped" messages. Which value do you want? The last one (0.0015797)? It may be useless if you miss previous two. You cannot get all values, because JVM does not save them anywhere. However, you can get cumulative value or the difference between two arbitrary points using the technique described in the answer.

Comment: @AndreiPangin Ok. But, maybe you know how to get correct stop the world time ?

Comment: @ArtemZatsev This depends on what you mean by "correct". `runtime.getTotalSafepointTime()` returns quite precise stop-the-world counter. This is what I personally use for monitoring production systems. Just read this counter periodically and subtract two subsequent values.

Comment: GC log file can give you a history of STW pauses, but for some reason it does not suit you. If you'd like to receive synchronous notifications about STW pauses, you'll have to patch [`RuntimeService::record_safepoint_end()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/e765322578aa/src/share/vm/services/runtimeService.cpp#l150) and rebuild HotSpot JVM from sources.

Comment: @AndreiPangin Understand. Thank You a lot !